# sqlite3-Errors in Code

Tags: c++, sqlite

I want to use SQLite in my c++-Code, so I included SQLite3. When I use the following code in an external *.exe, it works without any problems:

```
void create_Database(char * file_name)
{
    std::ofstream debug("C:\\Users\\Roland-User\\Desktop\\Debug.txt");
    //const std::string&filename = file_name;
    std::string filename = "C:\\Users\\Roland-User\\Desktop\\data";
    std::string appendix = ".database";
    std::string file = filename + appendix;
    debug << "Creating database\n";
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;
    char * sql;
    rc = sqlite3_open(file.c_str(), &db);
    if(rc)
        exit(-1);
    sql = "CREATE TABLE DATABASE(HEADERDATA INT, WAVENUMBER INT, POSX INT, POSY INT, COUNT INT);";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if(rc == 1)
    {
        sql = "DROP DATABASE DATABASE;";
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        sql = "DROP TABLE DATABASE;";
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        debug << "Having to drop database!\n";
    };
    sql = "CREATE TABLE DATABASE(HEADERDATA INT, WAVENUMBER INT, POSX INT, POSY INT, COUNT INT);";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if(rc!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        debug << "Still there are errors, I am confused!\n";
        debug << "With error codes: " << rc << '\n';
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        exit(-1);
    };
    debug << "Finished with creating database\n";
    debug.close();
    sqlite3_close(db);
};
```

But when I insert this code in a DLL, I always get an error in my second check (where I get the debug information: "With error codes: "). I always get the error code 1. How can I fix this, and what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you ignoring the error message?

Comment: What do you mean with that? Afaik this error code tells me that there is no database or there is a SQL error. But I just created a database, so there should be one. How can I find out the SQL Error?

Comment: I mean `zErrMsg`. Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html).

Comment: @CL: Ok, this is giving me a better error feedback, thank you for remembering me!